# Xcode navigation bar button crash

Tags: c, xcode, ipad, object, popover

I made a navigation bar with a button, the button shows my popovercontroller with a datepicker inside.
When I press the button it shows my popover correctly but when I press the button again, the app crashes.

What is the best solution to dissmiss the popovercontroller?

I tried:

```
if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

But that makes the popover disapear on touch.

And this solution does nothing at all:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to dismiss the popovercontroller . If you click on outside the popover it will automatically dismiss .

Comment: is does, but if some presses the button the app crashes. That should not be happening.

Comment: Can you debug and say at which line you are getting crash?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
if(![popOverController isPopoverVisible])
{
// MY CODE
}
else  {

[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];}
```